# Can Crawler4j be run from another class

Tags: crawler4j

I need to call Crawler4j from a different class. Instead of the main method in the Controller class I used a simple method called setup.

```
class Controller {
public void setup(String seed) {
    try {
        String rootFolder = "data/crawler";
        int numberOfCrawlers = 1;
        CrawlConfig config = new CrawlConfig();
        config.setCrawlStorageFolder(rootFolder);
        config.setPolitenessDelay(300);
        config.setMaxDepthOfCrawling(1);

        PageFetcher pageFetcher = new PageFetcher(config);
        RobotstxtConfig robotstxtConfig = new RobotstxtConfig();
        RobotstxtServer robotstxtServer = new RobotstxtServer(robotstxtConfig, pageFetcher);
        CrawlController controller = new CrawlController(config, pageFetcher, robotstxtServer);

        controller.addSeed(seed);
        controller.setCustomData(seed);
        controller.start(MyCrawler.class, numberOfCrawlers);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Tried to call it like this in another class, but props up an error.

```
Controller c = new Controller();
c.setup(seed);
```

Is it possible to not have a main method in the Controller class and still run crawler4j. In short, I would like to know how to integrate the crawler  in to my application which already has a main method. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I forgot to place an access modifier "public" before the class name. Hence the error. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no problem running Crawler like you want. The code below is tested and will work like expected:

```
public class Controller {

    public void setup(String seed) {
        try {
            String rootFolder = "data/crawler";
            int numberOfCrawlers = 4;
            CrawlConfig config = new CrawlConfig();
            config.setCrawlStorageFolder(rootFolder);
            config.setPolitenessDelay(300);
            config.setMaxDepthOfCrawling(2);

            PageFetcher pageFetcher = new PageFetcher(config);
            RobotstxtConfig robotstxtConfig = new RobotstxtConfig();
            RobotstxtServer robotstxtServer = new RobotstxtServer(robotstxtConfig, pageFetcher);
            CrawlController controller = new CrawlController(config, pageFetcher, robotstxtServer);

            controller.addSeed(seed);
            controller.setCustomData(seed);
            controller.start(BasicCrawler.class, numberOfCrawlers);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Controller crawler = new Controller();
        crawler.setup("http://www.ics.uci.edu/");
    }
}
```